# Looking for freeware that will backup lots of media (video/pictures) over multiple DVDs

Tags: backup, dvd

Conceptually I'm looking for something like dar, but I don't want it to make a special archive format, I'm just looking for a program that given a huge list of files in a directory tree will break them out into sections that will fill most (up to and including but not over) a measure of space like a DVD.
So what I'd be left with is a pile of DVDs with my original directory structure and all the files that would fit on one disc. So if I were to do a regular file copy of all the DVDs back to a file system I'd have what I started with.
Brasero for example says it will do it but doesn't actually seem to do it.
Linux better but windows acceptable.

Thanks.

P.S. I just found something called DVDspan. The only problem is when I run it, it blows up with an out of memory error. But that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I take it the reason you don't want to use something like a spanned ZIP file is because you need some kind of backup on a regular basis and you don't want to have to redo the whole DVD set?

Comment: no, more like I want to easily be able to sift through one dvd and not have to deal with an archive, I just want to be able to look at one disc and get at the files directly.

Comment: With that much space and file management I honestly think your best bet is a backup drive whether internal, networked, or external. But this doesn't really answer the question that you pose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a not-too-bad solution.

I wrote a program to do it for me.

I'll upload it to sourceforge so others can make use of it if they want.

Comment: Here it is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdsplit/